# How hot is supersonic intake air?

Tags: engine, jet, supersonic, temperature, inlet

How hot is the air at the compressor inlet at supersonic speed? For instance the Concorde at mach 2.2 or other jet engines at even higher speeds.

Comment: Are you interested in how the temperature varies with speed for a specific aircraft or in what is the maximal intake temperature for several supersonic aircraft designed to cruise a different speed (Concorde, SR-71, F-104, Mig-31,...)?

Answer (score 3):

The air entering the first compressor stage of the SR-71's engines could be as hot as 450C while at maximum cruise conditions. If that air got any hotter, it would begin to soften the compressor blades, and this put an upper limit on the speed of that plane.